# COMException occurred - Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME)) when trying to modify an existing excel file

Tags: vb.net, excel, com

3rd line returns COMException. oBooks.GetType().Invoke...

```
Dim oBooks As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = Me.fOpenXlsFile(strXLSFile)

Dim ci As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
oBooks.GetType().InvokeMember("Add", Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, oBooks, Nothing, ci)

For i As Int32 = 0 To objLv.Items.Count - 1
    oBooks.Styles.Item(i + 1).Interior.Color = objLv.Items(i).BackColor
Next
oBooks.Save()
```

Comment: There is no point in trying do write *both* late-bound code *and* early bound code.  You have a hard dependency on the interop library, you might as well use Application.WorkBooks.  If you don't have the Application object reference for some reason then get it from WorkBook.Application.  Big advantage is that you can't make a mistake like this, IntelliSense tells you that WorkBook doesn't have an Add() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to add a Workbook to another Workbook.  You need to add it to the Workbooks collection.  Something like this should work:

```
Dim wbs As Excel.Workbooks = oBooks.Application.Workbooks

wbs.GetType().InvokeMember("Add", Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, wbs, Nothing, ci)
```